setup.py egg_info did not run successfully while installing googletrans==3.1.0a0
We are getting following error on RHEL 8.4 server while installing specific googletrans==3.1.0a0.
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0


Collecting googletrans==3.1.0a0


Using cached googletrans-3.1.0a0.tar.gz (19 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error:    subprocess-exited-with-error 

`python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1`**
╰─> [29 lines of output]
/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:476: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
`!!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.
    
              By 2024-Sep-26, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
    
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
    
      !!
         opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
       /usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site- packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py:266: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'tests_require'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      /usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:318: InformationOnly: Normalizing '3.1.0-alpha' to '3.1.0a0'
        self.metadata.version = self._normalize_version(self.metadata.version)
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help
    
      error: invalid command 'egg_info'
      [end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details

Our Environment:
pd2adm@gcppcsdsl02a:/usr/sap/PD2/home#pip -V
pip 24.0 from XX/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
python3 -V
Python 3.8.13

I also ran pip check and following is output:
pip check

No broken requirements found.

pip show setuptools

Name: setuptools
Version: 70.0.0
Summary: Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages
Home-page: ``https://github.com/pypa/setuptools
Author: Python Packaging Authority
Author-email: distutils-sig@python.org

pip show wheel

Name: wheel
Version: 0.43.0
Summary: A built-package format for Python
Home-page:
Environement for user
env | grep PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/bin:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/ext/webservice-c/lib:/usr/sap/PD2/sap_bobj/enterprise_xi40/linux_x64:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataDirect/odbc/lib::/usr/sap/PD2/hdbclient:/usr/sap/PD2/oraclient/instantclient_12_1:/usr/sap/hostctrl/exe:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
NZ_ODBC_INI_PATH=
PATH=/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/ext/jre/bin:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/bin:/usr/sap/PD2/hdbclient:/usr/sap/PD2/oraclient/instantclient_12_1:/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/bin:/usr/sap/PD2/home/.local/bin:/usr/sap/PD2/home/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sysbin

which pip
/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/bin/pip
which python3
/usr/sap/PD2/dataservices/DataQuality/python/bin/python3

Please help to troubleshoot the issue.
I was expecting a successful installation of package. This has been installed successfully in QA environment but failing in production environment.
